# Extract Number from String Field Including Decimal SQL Server 18

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, substring, alphanumeric

I want to extract number from a string field including decimal in SQL.

My current code

```
substring(a.LastTitrate,patindex('%[0-9]%', a.LastTitrate),patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', a.LastTitrate)-patindex('%[0-9]%', a.LastTitrateCumulativeVolume)+1) as mL
```

My current results

```
0.542 mls    0
0.042 mls    0
0.317 mls    0
```

Desired Outcome

```
0.542 mls  0.542
0.042 mls  0.042
0.317 mls  0.317
```

Comment: Please read the instructions in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Can you tag the DBMS(presumably SQL Server) and its version?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: SQL Server 18. I also tried to update my questions. Appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A left with patindex will do.

```
select LastTitrate
, left(LastTitrate, patindex('%[0-9] ml%', LastTitrate)) as mL
from your_table
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for your help!